# Why addEventListener returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

This is the code: `let rockClick = rockBtn.addEventListener('click', playRound.bind("rock", computerPlay(), false));`

I `console.log` and it returns `undefined`. The `rockBtn`:`const rockBtn = document.querySelector("#rock");` should select the button with the id of `#rock` and when I click the button it should run the `playRound` function with `"rock"` as its first parameter and `computerPlay()` as the second. The `playRound` function **plays a single round of rock paper scissors**.

When I click the rock button, nothing happened so I put the `rockBtn.addEventListener` to a variable and `console.log()` it, and it returns `undefined`. Why is this happening? What should I do?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JaredDev/8syrwfm9/48/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code

1. `bind()` method, accept first argument `this` context, then the function parameters
2. I'm not sure what do you expect from returning a value from `addEventListener`, but yes it is void method, it returns `undefined`
3. If you want call `playGround` on `rockBtn` click, all you need is

```js
const rockBtn = document.querySelector("#rock");

rockBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        playRound("rock", computerPlay(), false)
    });
```

This is working fiddle of the example.

https://jsfiddle.net/h306pudt/

Comment: I now added the jsFiddle in my post. The `addEventListener` should run the `playRound` function and return the winner of the rock paper scissors game. I did this without the `bind()` but it didn't work so I tried using `bind()`. And I tried that arrow function but it still returns `undefined`

Comment: I just update the answer with working `fiddle`, please check.